# Whenever i tried to create react app it shows module not find

Tags: jquery, reactjs

It is showing the error mentioned below
Error: Cannot find module './node.js'
Require stack:

[image]

Comment: what command are you running?

Comment: what command did you run?

Comment: npx create-react-app

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. i.e. I tried using `npx create-react-app <FOLDER NAME>` or using `npx create-react-app .` and it showed the error. List out the full error. Also, when this happens I would put your Node.js version in the comment. This will help us help you get better comments/answers.